# Remove databases from Cygwin enviroment after compiling

Tags: cygwin

I'm running a script from the Cygwin bash prompt that compiles a windows .exe file. The process requires MySQL and PostgreSQL to be installed/compiled into the Cygwin environment. Everything works fine but what I would like to do is have my script remove MySQL and PostgreSQL after the compile process has been completed. I can't seem to find out how it is done.

The only reason to create a new compile is to add new database versions. I need to clean out the old databases in order to add the new databases for a new compile. The way I've been doing it is to just delete the complete Cygwin install and start over.

Below is the process that my script uses to compile the databases:

```
# Compiling PostgreSQL support for Barnyard2
cd /cygdrive/d/cygwin/postgresql-10.7
./configure
make && make install

# Compiling MySQL support for Barnyard2
cd /cygdrive/d/cygwin/mysql-8.0.15
cmake . -DWITH_EDITLINE=system -DINSTALL_MYSQLTESTDIR=
make mysqlclient && make install
```

Thanks...

Comment: usually `make uninstall` in the same directories

Comment: That worked for PostgreSQL but not for MySQL :(

Comment: check if the installation is under `/usr/local` and remove the files manually